# Find the header row where the last occurence of a value appears in sheet

Tags: excel

So I have 2 excel sheets where one excel sheet (say Sheet 1) contains some values and dates corresponding to those values. Header row contains the date and rows 2 to 6 contain the values. The other sheet (say Sheet 2) contains the list of all values that were entered in rows 2 to 6 of Sheet 1.

Sheet 1 usually gets updated in such a way that new records are added per column. For example, Sheet 1 has 3 new records, so columns B, C, and D are filled. I then want to retrieve the last occurrence of a certain value from Sheet 1 and record that last occurrence in Column B of Sheet 2. The last occurrence of that value occurs in, say cell D5 of Sheet 1, and I want to return the content of cell D1 in Sheet 2. If that value occurs again in cell F3 after another update, for example, cell F1 will be returned. A sample image is shown below, with the contents of Sheet 2 merged under the contents of Sheet 1.

[Sample problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlBy0.jpg)

What could be a possible formula for this? I have been trying to find possible formulas but all those solutions involve only one column or row as scope and not the whole sheet.

So far, what I'm only able to do is to return the index of the last occurrence of a certain value in just one column. See photo below.

[Index of last occurrence of value sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epXoc.jpg)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you show one of the solutions that you've come up with so far (the ones that work with just one column)? I think that'll make it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve. Also, you'll probably get more answers this way: here on StackOverflow questions that don't show some of the work you've done before asking for help are usually frowned upon.

Comment: Already edited the post with what I currently have, though it's still a long way because I'm still unable to return the adjacent cell, which is supposed to be the value to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The images you added show two different situations: the first one (Sample problem) has the dates on the first **row** and the second one (Index of last occurrence of value sample) has the dates on the first **column**. Still, I believe that the solution I'm proposing will work in both scenarios.

If you already figured how to get the column / line number, you can use the INDEX function to return the value at the first line / column.

For image #1:

```
= INDEX (1:1; 1; <your formula here>)
```

For image #2:

```
= INDEX (A:A; <your formula here>; 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try to test the formula based on the first image. Hopefully I get to come up with the full formula from there.